# Moshi parses List custom object to List that holds LinkedHashTreeMap

Tags: android, moshi

I have a list of custom objects that I want to parse and save in shared prefs.

```
internal fun putObjects(key: String, item: List<Any>) {
    val listJson = toJson(item)
    edit { it.putString(key, listJson) }
}

internal fun <T> getObjects(key: String): List<Any> {
    val json = prefs.getString(key, "") ?: ""
    val objectList: List<Any>? = fromJson(json)

    return objectList ?: listOf()
}
```

Moshi builder is created like this:

```
return Moshi.Builder()
        ...
        .addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
```

Expected result is `ArrayList<XObject>`, but instead Moshi returns `ArrayList<LinkedHashTreeMap<String, String>>`.